# Exportar tabla HTML a XLSX con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Estoy buscando como exportar una tabla HTML a Excel XLSX.
Pero no logro, solo logro exportarla a XLS, el otro falla.

Encontré esta respuesta que contiene los tipos, pero no he logrado aplicarlos de modo que el archivo descargado, no este roto.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nL7zdjt4/)

```js
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = '') {
  var downloadLink;
  var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
  filename = filename ? filename + '.xls' : 'excel_data.xls';
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
      type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('table_content', 'mtabla')">Exportar a excel</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="table_content">
  <thead class="thead thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th class='' scope="col">Sucursal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td scope='row'>datos de la tabla</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Exportar como `xlsx` va a ser complicado, porque realmente se trata de una colección de archivos comprimidos, pero si te sirve solo `xls`, puedes probar [este tutorial](https://redstapler.co/convert-html-table-excel-file-javascript/)

Comment: Podrías exportarla a `.csv` y se pueden abrir con Excel.

Comment: cerraré la pregunta, por que termine usando datatables, que ya tenia, solo que me falto agregar la opcion de exportar